# Share network with neighbor

Tags: network

My neighbor asked me if I wanted to share his network with me. Internet access is a little more expensive here than I am used to in my country. Before saying yes I wanted to know if I had risks in sharing my internet with him. He keeps the box and I will only have the wi-fi, which is enough for me, but about the security I don't want him to look at my bank passwords or something like that. I don't know if it's more risky than public wi-fi, but if someone can give me an idea or maybe advice.

Answer (score 3):

You are certainly adding risk though whether that is enough to worry about may be difficult to calculate.

1. Is it against the terms and conditions of use of the ISP? You both could get cut off. Low to medium risk, relatively low impact.
2. Will someone in their household do something illegal that you might end up on the hook for - because you cannot prove you were not complicit. Illegal file sharing, child pornography or something else. Medium risk, terrible impact.
3. You will be relying on their router being secure - it may well be now but will it always be? Medium risk but potentially high impact.
4. You will be using a wireless connection between houses, will anyone else create a rogue Wi-Fi hotspot that will intercept your connection? An unlikely issue generally but quite high impact.

I would estimate that the risks of all of that are far lower than public Wi-Fi but they are certainly nowhere near zero.

UPDATE: You could help mitigate some of these risks fairly readily. You could have a written and signed agreement for example. You could make sure your neighbours router created a VLAN and you could give them your own Wi-Fi access point so that your traffic was segmented from theirs.

Comment: I thought about a letter yes, but as you said it resolve some of these risks.

Comment: Remember this is an information security group, not legal advice.  1&2 are legal opinions and not appropriate advice to be offered here.

Comment: I'm sorry Steve but I disagree completely with your view. I have not offered any legal opinion and would not do so. I have outlined the possible RISKS and that is entirely appropriate. Indeed, I deliberately used the language of risk management.

Answer (score 1):

I think it comes down to how much you trust this person. Public Wifi can be dangerous because attackers can use things like packet sniffers to detect traffic and obtain passwords and other identifying information over the same network they're in. This guy could theoretically do the same without you knowing it. Depending on the network settings you have on your current system, he could have access to certain shares or drives you have created on your system that may be set to be accessible in a shared setup like that. That goes for anything you connect to the network too.

If you trust him, you have nothing to worry about. If you have any reservations, I'd probably hold off.

Comment: Trust is an odd thing. There are plenty of people I've trusted who have turned out to be involved with immoral or illegal activities, some of them pretty terrible. I don't think I have particularly dodgy contacts. It is only a tiny percentage of people but the impact on you from a neighbour being caught trading in child pornography for example might be catastrophic.

Comment: But if he does it's not me that will have theses files on my computer it's him normally no? so I should no really have problem, I don't know.

Comment: Truth. You never really know what's going on behind closed doors, and sharing a connection you're in the dark about doesn't seem to bode well, regardless of how much it might save.

Comment: To be honest I saw him one time... and he said that he have a good speed internet because he does bitcoin.., that we could test it etc. If I come on this forum it's for really know the risk I'm exposed if I do. If really it's better to have my own router, internet I will do.

Comment: Remember X-Files? Trust no-one. And secure your system accordingly.

Comment: I like to use a conversational analogy when it comes to internet connections. Sometimes it's better to have a conversation where it's only two people speaking, you and another party. Regardless of how secure that conversation may need to be, if you're okay with someone else potentially listening in on that conversation, and potentially adding on to it with whatever they choose to add, then you'll be okay sharing the connection. But again, it comes down to how much you trust that this person won't listen in and won't do something bad with the conversation.

Comment: @Nerm: It will not necessarily matter where the files are (or quite possibly are not) found. What may matter more is that someone tracked the downloading of files to the router. The router that you are sharing. The likelihood of this happening may be low but the potential impact is very high.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a vpn to encrypt your connection. Please make sure to keep updating the vpn version. Set up your network as being a public and not a home network to minimize the file sharing risk with other devices on the network.